# Is the trace of a product of positive definite matrices bigger than the sum of the product of their corresponding diagonal elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds, trace, positive-definite

Let $\mathbf{S},\mathbf{\Theta}\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ by symmetric, positive definite matrices. Denote their corresponding $(i,j)$-th component by $S_{ij},\Theta_{ij}$. Is it true that
\begin{align*}
\text{Trace}(\mathbf{S\Theta})\geq\sum_{i=1}^{p}S_{ii}\Theta_{ii}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.
Take $$A= \begin{bmatrix} 2& 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$B= \begin{bmatrix} 2& -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

No. If it is true, by a continuity argument, the inequality should still be true when $S$ and $\Theta$ are positive semidefinite, but it is not:
$$
S=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ -1&1},
\ \Theta=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}
\ \Rightarrow\ \operatorname{tr}(S\Theta)=0<2=\sum_iS_{ii}\Theta_{ii}.
$$